# Remove whiskers in boxplot made by ggboxplot (of ggpubr package)?

Tags: r, boxplot, ggpubr

Sometimes it is appropriate to show a boxplot without the whiskers.
In `geom_boxplot` (ggplot2) we can achieve this with `coef=0`.
Is there a way to achieve this in `ggboxplot` (ggpubr v0.5.0, current version at the time of writing)?
I note that `ggboxplot` has much in common with `geom_boxplot`,
such as the ability to use outlier.shape=NA in each case to suppress
outliers. It seems that there should be an easy way to also suppress the whiskers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find a way implemented in `ggboxplot` directly to do this, which is a bit strange because it passes the ellipsis to a `geom_boxplot` call, so I am not sure why the `coef=0` does not reach there and supresses the whiskers.
As a stopgap, you can modify the ggplot object created by `ggboxplot` and remove whiskers that way.
The following function shows this:

```
ggboxplot_whisker_opt <- function(...)
{
  opts <- list(...)
  # check if user specified a whiskers argument and set options accordingly
  if("whisker" %in% names(opts))
  {
    whisk <- opts$whisker
    opts$whisker <- NULL
  } else {
    whisk <- TRUE
  }
  pl <- do.call(ggboxplot,opts) # create plot by calling ggboxplot with all user options
  if(!whisk)
  {
    pl_list <- ggplot_build(pl) # get listed version of ggplot object to modify 
    pl_list$data[[1]]$ymin <- NA # remove the ymin/max that specify the whiskers
    pl_list$data[[1]]$ymax <- NA
    pl <- ggplot_gtable(pl_list) # convert back to ggplot object
  }
  # plot the ggplot and return
  plot(pl)
}
```

We can now call that function with `whisker=TRUE/FALSE` or without it and it produced plots accordingly:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
labels <- round(runif(100,1,2))
df <- data.frame(labels=labels,
                 value=x)

ggboxplot_whisker_opt(df,"labels","value") 
# is the same as 
ggboxplot_whisker_opt(df,"labels","value",whisker=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
ggboxplot_whisker_opt(df,"labels","value",whisker=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I learned something useful. Whilst you have answered the original question, I should update it. I wanted to go from `geom_boxplot` to `ggboxplot` so I could access labels like `stat_kruskal_test`. More effort required to produce a boxplot with no whiskers that can still give me such labels. If it is appropriate to update the question here, I will also put down the initial solution I found (based on yours). It adds some functionality, but I have problems with restricting the domain. Those who know more about `ggplot_build` than me will probably make it more elegant.

Comment: I have updated the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74567714/how-to-modify-ggboxplot-ggpubr-to-suppress-whiskers-but-retain-access-to-othe