# How to view standard deviation value along with mean value in boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate-functions, boxplot, ggpubr

CO2 Boxplot

[image]

I am trying to view "mean(+/-SD)" in box plot. I am using CO2 data. How to get "mean(+/-SD)" in the plot?

```
means <- aggregate(conc ~ Type, CO2, mean)

ggboxplot(CO2, x = "Type", y= "conc", color = "Type", palette = "jco", add = "jitter")+
  geom_text(data = means, aes(label = round(conc,2), y = conc + 10))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)+
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")
```

Comment: `fun.y` is a deprecated argument in `stat_summary()`. Check the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html) for more info.

Comment: I want to see +/- SD value along with the mean. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
add = c("jitter", "mean", "mean_sd")
```

ggpubr includes doing this visually as a specification to ggboxplot.[image]

Comment: And if you want SD but no whiskers [Remove whiskers in boxplot made by ggboxplot (of ggpubr package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74541555/remove-whiskers-in-boxplot-made-by-ggboxplot-of-ggpubr-package) has a function to remove whiskers.

Comment: I want to see +/- SD value along with the mean. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could pre calculate the mean and sd per group using `aggregate`. Here is a reproducible example using the `iris` dataset:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Long format
iris_long <- iris %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Species)

# Calculate mean and sd per group
ag <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(value ~ Species, iris_long, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))

# Plot
ggboxplot(data = iris_long, x = 'Species', y = 'value', color = 'Species', add = 'jitter') +
  geom_text(data = ag, mapping = aes(x = Species, label = paste0(round(value.mean, 2), '+-', round(value.sd, 2)), y = 8))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the answer. But its not working in CO2 dataset. When enterign this "CO2_long <- CO2 %>%   pivot_longer(cols = -Type)" I am getting this error "Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`: ! Can't combine `Plant` <ordered<2a6c8>> and `Treatment` <factor<0ac07>>. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred." Kindly help

Comment: Hi @VijayTalla, probably you have different classes of columns when converting to long format. You plant and treatment columns should have the same class when converting to long format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `ggboxplot` is, but you can achieve this using base `ggplot()` by passing `mean_sdl()` to the `data.fun` argument of `stat_summary()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(CO2,
       aes(x = Type, y= conc, color = Type, group_by = Type)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, colour = "darkred",
               shape = 18, size = 2)
```

[image: mean and standard deviation visualisation]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

`fun.y` is a [deprecated argument](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html). `fun.data` is a better argument for this purpose - it takes a function that sumamrises a vector into minimum, maximum and middle values before plotting. `mean_sdl()` returns the mean and the mean +/- the standard deviation.

Additionally, `show.guide` is a deprecated argument to `stat.summary()`

Comment: I want to see +/- SD value along with the mean. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: This plot is +/- SD along with the mean